# Read <property> value from file within build.xml

Tags: java, ant

Can I read the the property value from an external file instead of specifing the value within the `<property>` tag.

So instead of -

```
 <property name="device" value="test" />
```

Use something like

```
 <property name="device" value="c:\\fileToRead" />
```

where file to read contains test,test2,test3

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in build.xml

```
<property file="general.properties" />
```

general.properties file

```
svnant.version=1.0.0
lib.dir=${ant.home}/lib
```

So for you will be:

```
<property file="c:\\fileToRead" />
```

fileToRread is

```
 device=test
```

Comment: The variable device is referenced in the build.xml -

Comment: The variable device is referenced in the build.xml - <property name="devices" value="${device}"/> So I need to somehow initialise "device". I dont think using <property file> is valid in this regard ?

Answer (score 2):

The `<property>` task [provides a means](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html) to load a java properties file, if that's what you mean:

```
<property file="c:\\fileToRead"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. While you can't use the content of the file, you can use a file that looks like so:

```
device=C:\\fileToRead
```

and then read that with

```
<property file="foo.properties"/>
```

([see the docs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html)).